# how to check if remote host is running LDAP server?

Tags: webserver, nmap, ldap

I am currently pen-testing a remote website (its mine)

I would like to know if its possible to test if the web-server is running LDAP server.
I tried Nmap with no luck(it lists every port from 1 to 65389).
**e.g**

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
1/tcp     open     tcpmux
3/tcp     open     compressnet
4/tcp     open     unknown
6/tcp     open     unknown
7/tcp     open     echo
9/tcp     open     discard
13/tcp    open     daytime
17/tcp    open     qotd
19/tcp    open     chargen
20/tcp    open     ftp-data
21/tcp    open     ftp
22/tcp    filtered ssh
23/tcp    open     telnet
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why all of these services are showing as open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your server, you will know just by looking at the running services. When you are there, run `netstat` and probably you will see LDAP listening only on `localhost`.

Remotely, if the server is listening on `localhost`, you cannot know just by running `nmap`, the port will not answer for the public interface. You cannot access it even if it's running.

What you can do is use the [NMAP FTP Bounce](https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-ftp-bounce-scan.html) to scan the internal network.

PS: if this is your server, why would you run chargen, daytime and so? I haven't seen any legit use of those services since last century...

PPS: The last possible TCP port is 65535, not 65389...